# Is there a way I change the time ago text for a UILocalNotification?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

Is there any way I can change the "now" text in the screenshot?

I'm creating a calendar like app and would like to notify users 10 minutes before an event.
But the text "now" can be misleading.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure for 99% you can't. This is system-wide notification system and this label will show the time since the notification arrived and will then change to timestamp. I've seen no way to send notification to the past. If you find one - let me know.

Comment: I just wanted to replicate the behavior of the native calendar app. There is an option to send notifications 15 mins before the event etc. Is there any way I can achieve a similar behavior?

Comment: @vivek241 There is and that's how you do it)

Comment: Yea, but the problem the text shows "Event starting in 15 minutes". But the notification time shows "now" and that can be misleading.

Comment: @vivek241 I understand your question but you won't find a way to change this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36292/discussion-between-vivek241-and-sergiusgee)